# Swift 2 NOT bitwise operation does not behave as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, bitwise-operators, swift-playground

I am trying to flip all of the bits of a number in Swift using the bitwise NOT operator `~`

```
func binary(int: Int) -> String {
    return String(int, radix: 2)
}

let num = 0b11110000
binary(num) //prints "11110000"

let notNum = ~num
binary(notNum) //prints "-11110001"
```

It is my understanding that `notNum` should print out `00001111` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID29)) but instead it prints `-11110001`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a matter of bitwise operator, but a matter of behavior of the `String` initializer.
There are 2 `init(_:radix:uppercase:)` initializer in `String`

```
public init<T : _SignedIntegerType>(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)
public init<T : UnsignedIntegerType>(_ v: T, radix: Int, uppercase: Bool = default)
```

To get a expected result, you have to use `UnsignedIntegerType` one:

```
let num:UInt = 0b11110000
let notNum = ~num

String(notNum, radix: 2)
// -> "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111"
```

OR:

```
let num = 0b11110000
let notNum = ~num

String(UInt(bitPattern: notNum), radix: 2)
// -> "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100001111"
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats because you are using Int instead of UInt8:

Try like this:

```
func binary(uint8: UInt8) -> String {
    return String(uint8, radix: 2)
}

let num:UInt8 = 0b11110000
binary(num) //prints "11110000"

let notNum = ~num
binary(notNum) //prints "1111"
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that works. However I still don't understand why it doesn't work for signed integers. Shouldn't the negation operator work no matter how the integers are stored?